# pysnmp how to get all oids of network device using snmpwalk

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I want to know how to get all the oids of a certain network device in pysnmp.
This is my code:

```
        errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBind = cmdGen.nextCmd(
                    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
                    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
                    cmdgen.MibVariable('IF-MIB', '').loadMibs(), #get all oids
                    lexicographicMode=True, maxRows=10000,
                    ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True
                )

        for varBindTableRow in varBind:
            for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                print name, val
        print(len(varBind)) #prints number of oids
```

The problem is that I never get all the oids of the device(not even close actually).
Using this code i usually get around 90 but when i use snmpWalk.exe(downloaded from the internet) I usually get 700 each time.
I tried rewriting my code in many ways but nothing works.
Can someone please tell me how i can get all oids of a network device using pysnmp?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should get you up to 10000 OIDs starting from IF-MIB's first OID. Try walking your Agent starting from the first OID and make sure there is no intermittent error on the way of walking.

Also, keep in mind that your pysnmp code uses SNMP v2c. I'm not sure what SNMP version you used with snmpwalk.exe. Though unlikely, but it is theoretically possible that your SNMP Agent responds differently to SNMP v1 and v2c queries. I assume SNMP community is the same in both cases.

If nothing helps, try enabling pysnmp debugging to see what OIDs are requested, what OIDs are returned and whether and why pysnmp stops prematurely:

```
    from pysnmp import debug

    debug.setLogger(debug.Debug('msgproc', 'dsp', 'io', 'app'))

    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBind = cmdGen.nextCmd(
                cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
                cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
                '1.3.6',
                lexicographicMode=True,
                ignoreNonIncreasingOid=True
            )

    # make sure there's no timeout or other errors occurring at some point
    if errorIndication:
        print('WARNING: %s' % errorIndication)

    for varBindTableRow in varBind:
        for name, val in varBindTableRow:
            print(name, val)

    print(len(varBind)) #prints number of oids
```

Comment: I've updated my original answer with some new hints.